# Question related to direct sums

Tags: linear-algebra

The question and solution is shared below:-

[image: The question and solution]

I looked up the solution after attempting the question myself. And while I do understand the solution given above. I now have doubts about my own solution. The counter example according to me:-

$$V=\{(x,y)\,|\,(x,y) \in\mathbb R^2\}$$

$$U_1=\{(-x,0)\,|\,-x\in\mathbb R\}$$

$$U_2=\{(x,0)\,|\,x\in\mathbb R\}$$

$$W=\{(0,y)\,|\,y\in\mathbb R\}$$

As shown above, $$U_1\text{ and } U_2$$ are not equal. However, I haven't seen anyone define a subspace in such a way (by using -x) which is why I have my doubt.
I'd appreciate any feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your $U_1$ and $U_2$ are equal sets, you just defined them differently. $(1, 0)$ is still in $U_1,$ since $(1, 0) = (-(-1), 0),$ for instance. So, $U_1$ consists of the entire $x$-axis. Similarly, $U_2$ is just the entire $x$-axis. It's just like how $2/1$ and $4/2$ are the same number, or how $\{x \mid x \in (-1, 1)\}$ and $\{2x \mid x \in (-1/2, 1/2)\}$ are the same set.

Comment: I see. Now that I think about it, yeah you are correct. It was stupid of me to define it that way. Thank you

Comment: @Math_noob Not stupid. Just a sign of inexperience. The good news is that inexperience can be corrected more easily than stupidity can.